# Retrieving an image from Server to Client (Mongodb, React js, Node js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, node.js-fs

I am storing a user's information using mongoose. (Below is a quick summary of the code in Node js)

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate: validateUsername
    },


    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: validatePassword
    },

    image: {
        type: Buffer,
        required: false,
    },
```

I am storing the image as a Buffer using the fs module. (This is a default profile picture for the user)

```
const imagePath = './src/images/user.png'
const imageName = 'profile_pic'
const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(imagePath)

const user = new User({ username: username. password: password, image: imageBuffer})
```

and in the end I am sending over an object with the user's information alongside the access token and refresh token.

```
const new_user = {
                username: user.username,
                image: user.image,
                email: user.email,
                team: user.team,
                createdAt: user.createdAt,
                refreshToken: user.refreshToken,
                refreshTokenExpirationL : user.refreshTokenExpiration
            }
            
            const accessToken = jwt.sign(new_user, process.env.ACCESS_SECRET_TOKEN)
            const refreshToken = jwt.sign(new_user, process.env.REFRESH_SECRET_TOKEN)
    
            console.log("Logged in")
            res.status(200).send({accessToken: accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken, user: new_user})
```

This information is supposed to be stored as a cookie by the client.
However, the cookie can't be saved since the image buffer item is always too big.

So my question is, what is the best way to store an image and to retrieve it? Using mongodb, node js and react js.
Does my current way work or should i explore another option? For example i could try saving it elsewhere and retrieving the image using a link? I wish to try to keep things Local if possible but i am open for suggestions

Comment: You can look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75966660/11782285). It's a similar Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we're not storing images as buffer inside a database.
The best way to store images is in the server and store the url inside the database and use them.

That way helps to resolve a lot of problems,

1. you can cache images to serve them quickly after the first time they load,
2. your API response will be too small then it will receive quickly.
3. your images can load freely after your data been loaded.
4. that would give the user also a better experience.

Therefor my suggestion is to store the images in a file server and store the link on your database.

Comment: Okay makes sense, that was my other option as well. I am guessing using Multer. The retrieval shouldn't be slow either since we are accessing the file that we want.